# Loop over names in SAS-IML?

Tags: loops, sas, sas-iml

How can I read a SAS-Dataset with a name given as stem+suffix into IML? The stem is given as a SAS macro variable, the suffices I intend to use are in a string-vector in IML.

In R I would use

```
suffix<-c('s1','s2')
for (s in suffix){
   data<-eval(as.name(paste(stem,s,sep='')))
}
```

I could do the looping if I had the code for the first dataset. I tried:

```
proc iml;
suffices = {'s1','s2'};
call symput('suffix',suffices[1]);
use &stem.&suffix.;
```

The problem being that if in a do-loop (and I need this as I loop over names), call symput does not really work. [Here](https://communities.sas.com/thread/47154?start=0&tstart=0) i found symget, but in the context of use &stem.symget('suffix') was not fruitful.

Any other ideas?

Edit: I found the following rather inelegant solution:

```
proc iml;
%global suff;
suffix={'s1','s2','s3'};
%do ii = 1 %to 3;
call symput('suff',suffix[&ii.]);
<do stuff based on the suffix>
%end;
```

Still I do not feel this is the way one is supposed to work on it.

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult, but I don't think I totally understand what you're trying to do here.  What are you going to do with the datasets once you use them - are you going to use all of them and then do something, or are you going to use one, do something, and close it?

Comment: Every Table contains values for certain ages (rows) and generations (columns), plus a shift (indicated by suffix). I want to end up with a table
Age||Generation||Age+Generation+Shift||Value, combining the values for all tables (i.e. all shifts)

Comment: Have you looked at my solution?  If it's not sufficient, would you mind commenting as to why?  Your 'inelegant' solution is fine, although I don't suggest it only because it's putting data into code (the 1/2/3); that should really be in data proper.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to use some non-IML syntax.  PROC SQL for example can generate macro variable lists.

```
%let stem=class_;
data class_s1 class_s2;
set sashelp.class;
run;

data suffices;
input suffix $;
datalines;
s1
s2
;;;;
run;

%macro use_suffix(suffix=);
use &stem.&suffix.;
read all into &stem.&suffix.;
print &stem.&suffix.;
%mend use_suffix;

proc sql;
select cats('%use_suffix(suffix=',suffix,')') into :suffixlist separated by ' ' from suffices;
quit;

proc iml;
&suffixlist;
quit;
```

Comment: I did not think of generating a list thah holds commands. That was indeed eye-opening. However it did not solve my problem, as as far as I understand it, iml does not know any of the suffices, hence I do not know how to act based on them. (i.e. how would i do a if suffix=a then ... with that approach?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAS/IML 12.1, simply use string concatenation to construct the data set name, and then put parentheses around the name, as described in the blog post "[Read data sets that are specified in an array](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/29/read-data-sets-array-names/)".

Be careful when you try to use macro variables in a loop. See the tips in the article "[Macros and loops in the SAS/IML language](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/06/19/macros-and-loops/)"