# SAS IML use of Mattrib with Macro (symget) in a loop

Tags: macros, sas-iml, string-to-symbol

In an IML proc I have several martices and several vectors with the names of columns:

```
proc IML;
    mydata1 = {1 2 3, 2 3 4};
    mydata2 = {1 2, 2 3};
    names1 = {'red'  'green' 'blue'};
    names2 = {'black' 'white'};
```

To assign column names to columns in matrices one can copypaste the mattrib statement enough times:

```
    /*  mattrib mydata1 colname=names1;*/
    /*  mattrib mydata2 colname=names2;*/
```

However, in my case the number of matrices is defined at execution, thus a do loop is needed. The following code

```
    varNumb=2;
    do idx=1 to varNumb;
        call symputx ('mydataX', cat('mydata',idx));
        call symputx ('namesX', cat('names',idx));
        mattrib (symget('mydataX')) colname=(symget('namesX'));
    end;

    print (mydata1[,'red']) (mydata2[,'white']);
quit;
```

however produces the "Expecting a name" error on the first symget.

Similar question [Loop over names in SAS-IML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716726/loop-over-names-in-sas-iml) offers the macro workaround with symget, what produces an error here.

What is the correct way of using mattrib with symget? Is there other way of making a variable from a string than macro?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

---

EDIT1

The problem is in the *symget* function. The *&*-sign resolves the name of the matrix contained in the macro variable, the *symget* only returns the name of the macro.

```
proc IML;
    mydata1 = {1 2 3};
    call symputx ('mydataX', 'mydata1');
    mydataNew = (symget('mydataX'));

    print (&mydataX);
    print (symget("mydataX"));
    print mydataNew;
quit;
```

results in

```
mydata1 :   
1 2 3 

mydata1 

mydataNew :  
mydata1
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT2

Function *value* solves the *symget* problem in EDIT1

```
    mydataNew = value(symget('mydataX'));
    print (&mydataX);
    print (value(symget("mydataX")));
    print mydataNew;
```

The *mattrib* issue but persists.

---

**SOLVED**

Thanks Rick, you have opened my eyes to CALL EXECUTE() statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you use CALL SYMPUTX, you should not use quotes for the second argument. Your statement

```
call symputx ('mydataX', 'mydata1');
```

assigns the string 'mydata1' to the macro variable.

In general, trying to use macro variables in SAS/IML loops often results in complicated code. See the article [Macros and loops in the SAS/IML language](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/06/19/macros-and-loops/) for an indication of the issues caused by trying to combine a macro preprocessor with an interactive language.  Because the MATTRIB statement expects a literal value for the matrix name, I recomend that you use CALL EXECUTE rather than macro substitution to execute the MATTRIB statement.

You are also having problems because a macro variable is always a scalar string, whereas the column name is a vector of strings. Use the ROWCAT function to concatenate the vector of names into a single string.

The following statements accomplish your objective without using macro variables:

```
/* Use CALL EXECUTE to set matrix attributes dynamically.
   Requires that matrixName and varNames be defined at main scope */
start SetMattrib;
   cmd =  "mattrib " + matrixName + " colname={" + varNames + "};";
   *print cmd;    /* for debugging */
   call execute(cmd);
finish;

varNumb=2;
do idx=1 to varNumb;
    matrixName = cat('mydata',idx);
    varNames = rowcat( value(cat('names',idx)) + " " );
    run SetMattrib;
end;
```